# Setting an alias on the .net Portable Subset library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I'm using the nuget package `Microsoft.Net.Http` to add `HttpClient` to my PCL Domain Library.

I want to set a custom network credential, but I can't because of this error:

Code :

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
handler.Credentials = credentials;
_client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Error :

> Error 5   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.ICredentials [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile78\System.Net.Primitives.dll]' to 'System.Net.ICredentials'   C:[truncated]\ApiClient.cs 26  35  DeltekApi

The issue is that the `networkcredentials` I'm providing implement the nuget added implementation of `ICredentials`, and the interface `HttpClient` wants is the PCL `.Net Portable Subset` version.

Can't really think of a good way of fixing this?

Comment: What is the "nuget added implementation of ICredentials" that you refer to?  Is that from a NuGet package?  If so, which one?

Comment: This is the package: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug we had if you install VS 2012 Update 2 **after** the WP8 SDK.  Run a repair on the VS Update 2 installation to fix it.  See Issue 2 in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2840147) for more information.